# How to match word in a String contains multiple lines using pattern matcher of java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I've a String which contains multiple lines and i want to find a particular pattern in that multiple lines for example

```
String s = "foo\r\nbar\r\nfoo"
                + "foo, bar\r\nak  + "
                + "foo, bar\r\nak  + "
                + "bar, bar\r\nak  + "
                + "blr05\r\nsdfsdkfhsklfh";
```

Above String is a multiline String in which, i want to find "ak" and get the next word of it after `+` in my example its `foo,bar,blr05`

For this i created pattern `Pattern.compile("^ak\\s*+\\s*(\\w+)")` but its not working in `matcher.find()` itself returning false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a regular expression only matches text within a single line.  There are two ways of modifying this.  So one solution  that would suit you would be to write

```
Pattern.compile("^ak\\s*+\\s*(\\w+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Adding the extra argument gives you a `Pattern` that will match across multiple lines.

**Update**
As sln has pointed out, your original regular expression doesn't make much sense, because of the `+` following the `*`.  You probably meant `"^ak\\s*\\+\\s*(\\w+)"` - that is, escaping the `+` to make it a literal.

Comment: what would be the second way ?

Comment: Add `(?m)` to the front of the expression.  But I dislike doing that - the meaning of the second argument is somewhat more obvious.

Comment: If the plus is a literal, you'd have to escape it.